# Why is my Runnable .jar file not printing any messages in the terminal, when run from an Apple Script?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, applescript

I have compiled a jar file. Here is the code:

```
package javaProject;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        System.out.println("Enter something >>> ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Here is my Apple Script script:

```
do shell script "java -jar /Users/Harry/Desktop/appleScript.app/Contents/javaProject.jar"
```

Nothing is printed in the console, and the scanner object doesn't ask for my input at any point, but the JFrame is created. Can anyone explain why this is the case? Thanks.

Comment: `do shell script` doesn't run with/in a console, the result or error is just returned to the script.  You might try running it in Terminal.

Comment: Ok then. How do I run a .jar file that also prints messages in the Terminal/console, in which case???

Comment: `tell application "Terminal" to do script "your script"` should run it in a Terminal window/tab.

Comment: Oh ok! That works! Thanks very much for all of your help!

Comment: For some reason, i've just noticed that 2 terminal windows are opened (only one runs the script). Any idea why this happens?????

Comment: You get one when Terminal is first opened, then another is opened by the script unless you specify a window/tab.  I'll work up an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

`do shell script` doesn't run with/in a console, the result (or error) is just returned to the script.  If you are wanting to interact or view progress, the script can be run in something that does provide a console, such as the **Terminal** (which is scriptable).  Note that a new window/tab will be created each time you run a script, unless you specify something different - for example, the following script will always use the first tab of the first window:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    try
        do script "echo 'This is a test.' " in tab 1 of window 1
    on error errmess -- no window
        log errmess
        do script "echo 'This is a test.' "
    end try
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks so much for all of your help! It is very much appreciated!